# asp not rendering data

Tags: html, mysql, asp.net

I have the following code from a clients ASP page that shows schedules. There is data in the MySQL tables, and the connection is good. What is missing to make the page render the appropriate data? Page only renders the first start of the table and the rest of the page is blank.

```
<%
SQL1= "SELECT * FROM tbl_schedule  Order By BeginDate ASC"
Set cmd1 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")    
cmd1.ActiveConnection = Conn
cmd1.CommandText = SQL1
cmd1.CommandType = adCmdText
Set RS1 = cmd1.Execute()

IF NOT RS1.EOF THEN 'RS1


    Response.Write "<table border=2 frame=void rules=all cellpadding=2 cellspacing=0 width=800>"
    Response.Write "<tr valign=top><th width=225>Class</th>"
    Response.Write "<th width=25>Status</th>"
    Response.Write "<th width=150>Date</th>"
    Response.Write "<th width=100>Location</th>"
    Response.Write "<th width=100>Seats available</th>"
    Response.Write "<th width=100>Details &amp; Sign Up</th></tr>"
    Do until RS1.EOF

    IF RS1("BeginDate") > Date() THEN

    SQL2 = "SELECT Name as ClassName FROM tbl_lkup_classes WHERE ID = ?"
    Set cmd2 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")    
    cmd2.ActiveConnection = Conn
    cmd2.CommandText = SQL2
    cmd2.CommandType = adCmdText
    cmd2.Parameters(0) = RS1("Class")
    Set RS2 = cmd2.Execute()

    Response.Write "<tr valign=top>"
    Response.Write "<td>"&Trim(RS2("ClassName"))&"</td>"
    Response.Write "<td><font color=#b22222>"
        IF RS1("Status") = "A" THEN
        Response.Write "Active"
        End IF
        IF RS1("Status") = "C" THEN
        Response.Write "Cancelled"
        End IF
    Response.Write "</font></td>"
    Response.Write "<td>"&FormatDatetime(RS1("BeginDate"),1)&"</td>"
    Response.Write "<td>"&Trim(RS1("Location_city"))&", "&Trim(RS1("Location_state"))&"</td>"

        SQL3= "SELECT Count(Student_ID) as ClassCount FROM tbl_roster WHERE Class_ID = ?"
        Set cmd3 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")    
        cmd3.ActiveConnection = Conn
        cmd3.CommandText = SQL3
        cmd3.CommandType = adCmdText
        cmd3.Parameters(0) = RS1("ID")
        Set RS3 = cmd3.Execute()
        strSlotsAvailable = Cint(RS1("Slots")) - Cint(RS3("ClassCount"))
        Response.Write "<td align=center><div align=center>"&strSlotsAvailable&"</div></td>"
        Response.Write "<td align=right><a href=ClassDetails.asp?RecID="&RS1("ID")&">Details &amp; Sign up</a></td></tr>"

    END IF
    RS1.MoveNext
    LOOP
    Response.Write "</table>"


Else 'RS1

Response.write "There are no currently scheduled classes.<br /><br />"

end If 'RS1
%>
```

Comment: Do any of your records have a `BeginDate` later than `Date()`?  I suggest you add some debug statements while you're working it out. For example, comment out the two internal data retrievals, and put an `ELSE` on that outer `if` so you can `Response.write "Starts before today"` or similar

Comment: What do you mean by "Page only renders the first start of the table"? Does this mean just the table's first row is rendered, the first ten (10) rows, or something else?

Comment: all dates so far are for later dates and none for the future at the moment. I will try adding a future date and some debugs statements to see where we are in the code.